# ACL in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have one doubt !

User group

```
|—  Manager
|—|— Administrator
```

Manager is the parent,Administrator is the child..right ?

But the administrator have permission for to edit the Manager profile ? how its possible ?

Any one please explain me

Answer (score 3):

Not quite. Think of it more in relation to inherited permissions rather than a parent-child relationship. 
The reason it is shown like that is that Administrator, by default, inherits all of the permissions that the manager has + has some extra. So Administrator has more permissions that the manager does.
Attached is a sample of the default permission [image]setup.

OK, so answering comment relating to permissions for your component. To set the permissions for a specific component (rather than global permissions) one would go to the components menu, select the component and set the permissions in there. e.g. see the attached image for Joomla's built in Banner Manager, under Components | Banners, click on the Options icon and then on the Permissions tab. See the default here.

The Manager has access to lots of functionality here, but you can change the dropdowns from Inherited and Allowed to Disable to stop managers from being able to do anything in this component. Likewise you could give more access to other user groups, etc. So, for example, if you only want Super admins to be able to access the component, just set manager and administrator to "Denied" and set super-users to Allowed.

[image]

Comment: ok Trev!..i want to do like this!..i am developing one component,in this if a lead is assign to manager group,all users in manager group + super admin will access that leads..if it assign to super admin,that lead only for super admin...how to do this ! example is enough !

Comment: OK, I think I know what you mean. I'll update the post above as I can't add an attachment in this comment.